# Load an Embedded You Tube or Vimeo Video in Simple Modal

Tags: video, vimeo, simplemodal

The website is a little tricky to use. But I am looking to simply load and embedded vimeo video into the modal without using an iframe tag. I know this is possible but haven't seen too many examples of this. Any info will help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I use the [squeezebox](http://digitarald.de/project/squeezebox) library with an anchor assigned the class of modal.

```
<script>
    window.addEvent('domready', function () {
        SqueezeBox.assign($$('a.modal'), {
            parse: 'rel'
        });
    });
</script>
<a class="modal" href="http://www.youtube.com/v/b4mnFExyAm8?version=3&amp;autoplay=1&amp;rel=0;fs=0;modestbranding=1;" rel="{handler: 'iframe', size: {x: 800, y: 480}}" title="Some Modal Embed Video">Embed Modal</a>
```